# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Session: 766972672. No packages staged in /data/app/vmdl766972672.tmp]

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, dynamic-feature-module

Struggling with **INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK**, only if installation is done in **Android 11(API 30)** below this version app installation is fine and specifically issue starts with 2nd onward install attempts(since 1st install attempt successes always), given that my base(app) module uses **dynamicFeature**.

Below are the logs

```
I/studio.deploy: DeltaInstall found API level:30
I/studio.deploy: -t
I/studio.deploy: --user
I/studio.deploy: current
I/studio.deploy: --full
I/studio.deploy: --skip-verification
I/studio.deploy: -r
I/studio.deploy: -p
I/studio.deploy: com.example.mobile.android.mydynamicfeature
I/studio.deploy: DeltaInstall created session: '766972672'
I/studio.deploy: Skipping '/data/app/~~eIfs_Dhf2kcksHvQ5cuRyQ==/com.example.mobile.android.mydynamicfeature-pmtDNQbD68r8aVgRJmdR2A==/split_feature_one.apk' since inheriting mode and apk did not change
I/studio.deploy: Skipping '/data/app/~~eIfs_Dhf2kcksHvQ5cuRyQ==/com.example.mobile.android.mydynamicfeature-pmtDNQbD68r8aVgRJmdR2A==/split_feature_two.apk' since inheriting mode and apk did not change
I/studio.deploy: Skipping '/data/app/~~eIfs_Dhf2kcksHvQ5cuRyQ==/com.example.mobile.android.mydynamicfeature-pmtDNQbD68r8aVgRJmdR2A==/split_feature_three.apk' since inheriting mode and apk did not change
I/studio.deploy: Skipping '/data/app/~~eIfs_Dhf2kcksHvQ5cuRyQ==/com.example.mobile.android.mydynamicfeature-pmtDNQbD68r8aVgRJmdR2A==/base.apk' since inheriting mode and apk did not change
I/studio.deploy: package
I/studio.deploy: install-commit
I/studio.deploy: 766972672
E/studio.deploy: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Session: 766972672. No packages staged in /data/app/vmdl766972672.tmp]
```

Kindly look & advice, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May be you have the installer file inside any of the external private storage location. Try to move them to internal private locations and retry. I mean it will work if it is in `getFilesDir()`, but not if inside `getExternalFilesDir(null)`.

Hope this clarifies what I am trying to say.